# horizontal list with image and text

Tags: css

For each list item, I want an image with text below the image.
I read on this [technique](http://gtwebdev.com/workshop/layout/inline-block-gallery.php), but it is not supported in IE.  Instead, I'm floating the list items to the left.  It does the trick except the content below the list wraps to the right. How do I prevent the content from wrapping this way?
Here is my code:

```
<style>
    .horizlist{
        list-style:none;
        text-align:center;      
    }
    #menulist ul{
        width:360px;
    }
    #menulist li{
        float:left;
        padding-right:50px;
    }
    #menulist li img{
        display:block;
    }
</style>
<div id="container" style="">
    <div id="top">
        <img src="joblove.jpg" style="float:right;">
        <div id="title" style="width:500px;text-align:center;">
        <h1>"THE TOUGHEST JOB YOU'LL EVER LOVE:"</h1>
        <p style="font-size: 1.6em;">A RESOURCE FOR THOSE THINKING ABOUT A CAREER IN DIRECT CARE</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menulist">
        <ul class="horizlist" >
            <li>
                <a href="home"><img src="images/purplestyle_11_home.png"></img><span>Home</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="brochure"><img src="images/purplestyle_01_heart.png"><span>Brochure</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="video"><img src="images/purplestyle_05_cut.png"><span>Video</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="personality"><img src="images/purplestyle_15_buddies.png"><span>Personality</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="resources"><img src="images/purplestyle_03_folder.png"><span>Resources</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="FAQ"><img src="images/purplestyle_02_talk.png"><span>FAQ</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img src="phone.jpg">
    <ul class="horizlist">
        <li><button type="button">Click </li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: IE8+ supports inline-block just fine.

Comment: Is this why it didn't work when I tested it?

Answer (score 1):

Add an height to #menulist in css :

```
 #menulist ul{
    width:360px;
    height:100px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS backgrounds. They give you more control over image positioning and require less mark-up.

HTML:

```
<a class="home" href="home">Home</a>
```

CSS:

```
.horizlist a {
   display:block;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   padding-top: 20px;
   padding-left: 20px
   background-position: 10px 10px;

a.home {
   background-image:url(/images/purplestyle_11_home.png);
}
```

Can can adjust the padding and background-position values to suit. Repeat as needed.